# JNLP application returns NULL for all System.getenv()

Tags: environment-variables, java-web-start, jnlp

I've a JNLP Java WebStart application in Which I want to read form the Environment Variables but all of them are NULL.

In my JNLP application I access and print the variables the following way:

```
Map<String, String> envArgs = System.getenv();
for (String key : envArgs.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "=" + arguments.get(key));
}
```

And Prints just lines like this:

> ProgramData=null
>   ProgramW6432=null
>   HOMEPATH=null
>   PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=null
>   ProgramFiles=null
>   PUBLIC=null
>   windir=null
>   MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_PING_DIRECTORY=null

The JNLP application is started form another Java Application using the ProcessBuilder `cmd = "C:\JDK\jre\bin\javaws -wait URL2JNLP"`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0], cmd[1], cmd[2]);
pb.environment().put("apple", "isFruite");

try {
    return pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Error starting JNLP application", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Is there a way to fix this access/passing of the environment variables?